# Regex Lookahead in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying to find certain strings in my tables.
I need to display only the records that have those characters.
For example I have this table:

```
TABLE_A
=================
 # | COL_A
=================
 1 | ABC
 2 | _ABC_
 3 | _ABCD_ABC_
 4 | ABCD
```

I want to select all records that has ABC but not ABCD.
In the example table above, records 1, 2 and 3 should be displayed.
The best I came up with now currently is this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(COL_A, 'ABC[^D]{1,}', 'inm');
```

The problem with the statement above is that if there's only ABC at the end of the data, it won't be displayed.

PS: Is this even doable in pure SQL?

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are not storing lists in delimited strings.

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language - you are only using SQL.

Comment: What are the delimiters?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, this is not actually a list. It's just sample data for this question. In the actual environment, they are remarks, descriptions, names, etc. Sorry for misguiding you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[^D]|$` to match a non-`D` character or the end-of-line:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_A
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(COL_A, 'ABC([^D]|$)', 'i');
```

Comment: If I just need to add exclusions, I just need to add it inside the brackets, right? For example, [^DZ] if I don't want to match ABCD and ABCZ.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `like`:

```
where '_' || col_a || '_' like '%$_ABC$_%' escape '$'
```

However, storing multiple codes in a single column is not the SQLish way to store data.  You should fix your data structure, particularly if you care at all about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Look for rows where `'ABC'` is preceeded by the start of the line or an underscore and proceeded by an underscore or the end of the line.

```
SQL> with table_a(ID, col_a) as (
     select 1, 'ABC'        from dual union all
     select 2, '_ABC_'      from dual union all
     select 3, '_ABCD_ABC_' from dual union all
     select 4, 'ABCD'       from dual
   )
   select id, col_a
   from table_a
   where regexp_like(col_a, '(^|_)ABC(_|$)');

        ID COL_A
---------- ----------
         1 ABC
         2 _ABC_
         3 _ABCD_ABC_

SQL>
```